# Were the lightsabers used by younglings different from the regular lightsabers used by Jedi or Sith?

Tags: star-wars

On the comment to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/218485/why-did-the-galactic-republic-allow-a-religious-cult-to-brainwash-and-arm-young) question, a guy said that

> those weren't TRUE lightsabers. They were training-level sabers.

[image]

These lightsabers look real (with saber length adjustment) to me which can do real damage including killing. How else can you build a glowing stick which can be turned on or off like the lightsabers Jedi or Sith own? On the other hand, this is the galaxy far far away we are talking about in which technology is comparable to magic.

I want to know from the canon (with proper citation): Could those lightsabers do real damages including death? Were they stripped down versions of the "true" lightsabers which Jedi or Sith own?

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Training_lightsaber/Legends

Comment: @MissouriSpartan That's not canon reference, but yes thanks for the link.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is a canon side to that page, and while it's not abundantly populated with references it at least shows that the concept - if not the specific execution - is canon.

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Training_lightsaber to be specific

Comment: The dupe explicitly addresses this point; "*They boast a stronger containment field so that the weapon can bruise at best. According to the Star Wars wikia entry, they are adjustable to be able to do more damage, but presumably it requires someone with a fair degree of knowledge to disable the safety interlocks.*". You can check the citations on the article to find the canon confirmations.

Comment: OK, I'm officially confused. When the younglings went on their quest to gain a kyber crystal in Clone Wars - The Gathering and subsequently assembled their own lightsabers, were the lightsabers somehow 'made safe'? They seem to work well enough to me in succeeding episodes.